# Error getting session token in IBM Notes Agent

Tags: java, session, lotus-notes

I'm trying to create an IBM Notes agent (written in java) that gets the session token associated with the agent.  (The intent is to then pass it as a cookie to an HttpURLConnection xpage request.)  When I call session.getSessionToken() in the agent, however, I get an exception and see this in the server console:

> Notes error: Creating administration request to create mail file for %A...

Does anyone have any insight as to why it's not working?  The server this is running on does use single sign on.  TIA.

Comment: What type of agent is this? How is it triggered?

Comment: It's a scheduled agent, so it runs periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Session.getSessionToken() is defined for scheduled or triggered agents that run in the Agent Manager, because agents like that aren't associated with an authenticated web user session.

Comment: I don't understand how these things work, but that's certainly believable.  I was hoping it wasn't the case.  This post describes what I'm trying to do, FYI, and a commenter at the end posted about getting the token, and that's in the context of a scheduled agent.  Ah well.

Comment: Here is the post I was referring to: http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/m.leusink/entry/using_scheduled_xpages?lang=nl